# Steam window not clickable - Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics, lubuntu, steam

After upgrading to Lubuntu 16.04 from 15.10 I found a strange problem - Steam login window will appear, but when I try to click on it or manipulate with some other window, it gets simply "overwritten" with surrounding graphics, like parts of another window etc. And the "click" has no other effect.

It looks like this:
[image]

It's really strange and I've never encountered similar error before. The even stranger part is, that this problem occurs only with Steam and nothing else.

---

**I have tried** to completely reinstall `steam` and `steamcmd` packages and even manually remove `/home/.steam/` folder, but nothing worked.

It appears, that all Steam processes get suspended, but I have no idea why:
[image]

---

Do you know, how can I repair it?

Comment: It looks like Steam froze up. Did you let it sit for a bit to see if it became responsive?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I tried that too, but nothing. I've edited my question  - it appears that Steam processes are suspended or something like that.